# RichFaces : render several components in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, richfaces

I'm trying to rerender 2 components of my page. No problem in Firefox or Chrome, but in IE only one component is rerendered.

Those renderings should occur when the value of an input is changed. So, I wrote this code :

```
<h:inputText id="componentID" value="#{myValue}">
    <f:converter converterId="myConverterID"/>
    <a:ajax event="change" listener="#{myListener}"
            render="renderIDOne,renderIDTwo" execute="@this" />
</h:inputText>
```

I already tried to use space separated components ID's.
For your information, I'm using RF 4.2.

Is there someone to help me ? Thanks in advance.